# extend/append a list for saving as geometry in a geodataframe

Tags: geometry, append, geopandas, extend

how to use append and extend? and accumulating polygons and points, and then saving it as geometry

```
pointlist=[]
polylist=[]
for j,i in land:
     pointlist.append(Point(lon[i],lat[j]))
     pointlist.append(list(Point(lon[i],lat[j]).geometry))
     pointlist.extend(Point(lon[i],lat[j]))

     poly=[(lon[i],lat[j+1]),(lon[i+1],lat[j+1]),(lon[i+1],lat[j]),(lon[i],lat[j])] 
poly = Polygon(poly)
     polylist.append(poly)
     polylist.append(list(poly.geometry))
     polylist.extend(poly)

shp_1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polylist)
shp_1.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
shp_2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=pointlist)
shp_2.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
```

an error always appears when creating the geodataframe, it does not recognize the list as geometry

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
or
TypeError("Input must be valid geometry objects: {0}".format(geom))

any ideas?

Comment: `polylist`  is not yet geometry object.

Comment: yes it is a polygon

Comment: Can you share sample of your original data? If it is sensitive data, remove the sensitive part.